# Questions about my SQL queries in SQL exercise (Unable to find the column)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am doing some SQL exercises and the requirement is as follows:

For every situation where student A likes student B, but we have no information about whom B likes (that is, B does not appear as an ID1 in the Likes table), return A and B's names and grades.

And I have a reference about the schema: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html

and my query is as follow:

```
select 
    h1.name, h1.grade, h2.name, h2.grade
from 
    highschooler h1, highschooler h2, likes l1, likes l2
where 
    h1.id in (select id1 
              from l1 
              where not exists (select id2 from l1 where id2 = id1)) 
    and h2.id in (select id2 
                  from l2 
                  where not exists (select id2 from l2 where id2 = id1))
```

The SQL is built in html server and it keeps telling me that they are unable to find column l1. Is there any logical error in my code and can someone tell what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your query is pretty messed up... and your business case is also not very much clear.. Can you explain it little more?

Comment: Thank you marc_s for pointing out yhe bad habit. I will avoid of using comma and try to use join next time.

Answer (score 1):

You should better work with joins ... give it a shot with something like this

```
Select HS1.ID, HS1.Name, HS1.grade,
       LI1.ID1, LI1.ID2,
       HS2.ID, HS2.Name, HS2.Grade
from Highschooler HS1
join Likes LI1 on HS1.ID = LI1.ID1 
JOIN Highschooler HS2 on LI1.ID2 = HS2.id
LEFT JOIN Likes LI2 on HS2.ID = LI2.ID1
where LI2.ID1 IS NULL
```

Basically you just joining these tables and last 2 lines will give you what you asked for ... "but we have no information about whom B likes (that is, B does not appear as an ID1 in the Likes table)" ... take a look at joins and fix this query ... i just took a glance at problem to point you towards right direction

Comment: Thanks! I get your direction.